# To Determine if a .exe file is an setup file

Tags: c++, kernel, wdk

I need to write a c/c++/kernel driver program where I can check if an .exe file is an Setup file where I can install new application in my computer (Like an .MSI file) or an normal application (For Example: If I Open an .exe file which is named as chorme.exe then it is an normal window application which only opens chrome browser , but if I Open an .exe file which is chromeinstaller.exe it is an installer which installs chrome browser in my computer).

Is there any way to determine if it's a setup file or just a application.

Comment: What makes you assume that this is a binary choice? IIRC a number of Sysinternal tools do both - they install a driver and run an UI.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of it but I need to know if it is possible to classify it as a setup file or an windows application

Comment: Didn't you post exactly this yesterday, and get the answer "you can't do that reliably"?

Comment: @molbdnilo: It looks like that. While the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72429864/to-check-if-a-exe-file-is-an-installer-applicationsetup-or-a-normal-windows-a) (now deleted) is asked by the other user, it has the very **same wording**.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft itself *tried* to solve this with ["Installer Detection"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc709628(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) , and from their solution it becomes obvious that there is no hard solution. They look for:

- Filename includes keywords like "install," "setup," "update," etc.
- Keywords in the following Versioning Resource fields: Vendor, Company Name, Product Name, File Description, Original Filename, Internal Name, and Export Name.
- Keywords in the side-by-side manifest embedded in the executable.
- Keywords in specific StringTable entries linked in the executable.
- Key attributes in the RC data linked in the executable.
- Targeted sequences of bytes within the executable.

We can safely assume they're doing this because there is no ready-made solution.